# What is the appropriate way to find index number in list in python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I would like a output like bellow image.

```py
def print_list(lists):
    for i in lists:
        print(f"List{index()} = " + i)


fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
print_list(fruits)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate()`:

```
def print_list(lists):
    for idx, i in enumerate(lists):
        print(f"List[{idx}] = {i}")


fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
print_list(fruits)
```

Prints:

```
List[0] = apple
List[1] = banana
List[2] = cherry
```